# Receiving packets in c# using threading

Tags: c#, java, multithreading, unity-game-engine

I am following a Java example that uses a Completion Service to submit queries to a 3rd party app that receives packets by calling:

```java
completionService.submit(new FetchData());
```

Then it calls:

```java
Future<Data> future  = completionService.take();
Data data = future.get(timeout, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
```

Which waits for one of the submitted tasks to finish and returns the data. These two calls are in a `while(true)` loop.

I am developing an app in c# and I was wondering if this is the proper way to wait for packets and if it is how do I do it in c#.

I have tried this but I'm not sure if I am doing it right:

```cs
new Thread(delegate() {
  Dictionary<ManualResetEvent, FetchData> dataDict = new Dictionary<ManualResetEvent, FetchData>();

  ManualResetEvent[] doneEvents;
  ManualResetEvent doneEvent;
  FetchData fetch;
  int index;

  while(true) {             
    // Create new fetch
    doneEvent = new ManualResetEvent(false);
    fetch = new FetchData(this, doneEvent);

    // event -> fetch association
    dataDict.Add(doneEvent, fetch);

    ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(fetch.DoWork);

    doneEvents = new ManualResetEvent[dataDict.Count];
    dataDict.Keys.CopyTo(doneEvents, 0);

    // wait for any of them to finish
    index = WaitHandle.WaitAny(doneEvents, receiveThreadTimeout);

    // did we timeout?
    if (index == WaitHandle.WaitTimeout) {
      continue;
    }

    // grab done event
    doneEvent = doneEvents[index];
    // grab fetch
    fetch = dataDict[doneEvent];

    // remove from dict
    dataDict.Remove(doneEvent);

    // process data
    processData(fetch.GetData());               
  }

}).Start();
```

EDIT: One last note, I am using this in Unity which uses Mono 2.6 and is limited to .NET 2.0

EDIT 2: I changed the code around some. I realized that the ThreadPool has its own max limit and will queue up tasks if there are no threads left, so I removed that logic from my code.

Comment: Use the `Task` class and the TPL.  It's much much easier.

Comment: Sorry forgot to mention that I am using Unity which means I can't use any .NET 4.0 stuff

Comment: The tag unity is for Microsoft Unity. Please don't misuse it.

Answer (score 0):

Do you really need to use multithread in your Unity3D application? I'm asking this because Unity "is not" multi-threaded: there's a way to deal with threads but you'd better rely on *coroutines* to do this. Please refer to [this documentation](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/index.Coroutines_26_Yield.html) to find more about coroutines.

One note: if you are using Unity 3.5, it uses Mono 2.6.5 that supports almost everything of .NET 4.0. I don't know about the `Task` class, but it certainly covers .NET 3.0.

Comment: Ok thanks, I wasn't positive about what version of .NET Unity3D supports, I wasn't able to find concrete information. I know for a fact that it doesn't support the `Task` class.

As for the multithreading, I have heard there are problems, I thought I would experiment, I will probably fall back on coroutines otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that I only need a single thread to listen for packets, so I don't have to use a thread pool like in my example above.